# Google plus Login and Google maps are not working after app is published on Play Store

Tags: android, google-maps, release

I have the problem while sign in using Google and displaying Google Maps. Recently, I changed package names and got into this problem. 
I know for the app to be work fine it has to be released in the Signed mode and then upload it to Google play. I did the same, the app is completely working in release mode but it's not working when I download it from Google play. I changed the package name in Android Manifest and build.gradle file.

Also, I create the new project on Google console and create new keys by enabling the Google Maps API and Google plus API. Now, I am not able to figure out the problem.

I created keys multiple times and try to upload build every time with updated keys but the problem does not solved.
It would be great if someone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to app Signing section under App release in Google play, here you can find a new SHA-1 key, upload that key in Firebase and everything starts working.

Answer (score 0):

You should create Google Maps and Google plus API keys for release mode. If you have done so check whether Package name and release key are correct on Google developer console. Also make sure you have added Google Maps and Google plus API keys on xml file on release folder as seen on screenshot.
[image]

Comment: I created keystore file and generate it SHA-1 key and update that key on Google console too, and it does work on release build of my app but when I upload the same on Google play, it does not work.

Comment: Yes I unpublished the last one and create a new one and published the new one.

Comment: So the package names are different from each other?

Comment: Yes, That's why I create a new project

Comment: did you create a new keystore file for new project or using older one?

Comment: I create the new keystore file.